# Picking a Phone Number From a String (Regex)

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression to pick a phone number from a string, where the format of the phone number could be just about anything, or there may not be a phone number at all. For example:

```
$string = 'My phone number is +34 961 123456.';
$string = 'My phone number is +34 (961) 123456.';
$string = 'My phone number is 961-123456.';
$string = 'My phone number is +34.961.12.34.56.';
$string = 'Product A costs €100.00 and Product B costs €134.15.';
```

So far, I have got to

```
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9\/\+\.\-\s]+/", "", $string);
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $number);
if (strlen($number)>8) {
/* It's a phone number, so do something with it */
}
```

This works for picking out all the different phone number formats that I have tried, but it also puts the prices together and assumes that they are a phone number too.

It seems that my problem is that a human can readily distinguish between a space between words and a space in the middle of a phone number, but how do I make the computer do that? Is there a way that I can replace spaces that are both preceded and followed by a number but leave other spaces intact? Is there some other way of sorting this out?

Comment: The answer to the "duplicate" question only works when all digits in the input belong to phone numbers

Comment: instead of `+` Using a quantifier should help `{n,}` (n or more times)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want sequences of nine to twelve digits, with nothing between them except spaces, parentheses, periods or dashes; and possibly preceded by `+`. Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/\+?(?:\d[-. ()]*){9,12}/", $string, $results);
```

This isn't quite perfect, since trailing punctuation (like the period that follows all your examples) will be included in the matched string. Post-process the list of results to trim it:

```
preg_replace("/[-. ]+$/", "", $results);
```

Or you could standardize the collected phone numbers by removing all non-digits from the results, keeping just the digits and possibly an initial "+":

```
preg_replace("/[-. ()]/", "", $results);
```

Comment: I think you're right. I've tried your code and it throws up an error "preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash". Unfortunately I don't understand your synta well enough to try to debug it.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to put the slashes around the regexp! Fixed.

Comment: That solved it. I put in the slashes and it worked. I was already on top of the issue of the full stop if the number comes at the end of a sentence: remove it with rtrim and put it back in at the end. Thanks alexis.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you aren't gonna like it. The regex I get is this:

```
(\+?[0-9]?[0-9]?[[:blank:],\.]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][[:blank:],\.]?[0-9][0-9][[:blank:],\.]?[0-9][0-9][[:blank:],\.]?[0-9][0-9])
```

Explanation:

```
( <-- is for "grouping" and get the regular expression, probably not needed here
\+? <-- optional plus sign
[0-9]?[0-9]?  <-- optional prefix code 
[[:blank:],\.]? <-- optional space (or comma or dot) between the prefix code and the rest of the number
[0-9][0-9][0-9][[:blank:],\.]? <-- optional province code 
[0-9][0-9][[:blank:],\.]?[0-9][0-9][[:blank:],\.]?[0-9][0-9] <-- number, composed by six numbers
```

Because these examples are for spanish telephone numbers, aren't they???

In that case, you've forgotten to give us examples of other formats, like "91 123 45 67", that might complicate the solution even more.

For these cases, I humbly think that is a best solution to make a little function. The regular expression is too complex to be a maintenable solution.

Comment: They could be any country. I just used +34 as an example. That's why I am trying to isolate any part of the string that contains only numbers and the various characters that are sometimes included in phone numbers. Then if that part string is longer than a price, it must be a phone number.

Comment: The format of the telephone numbers in france is 0X XX XX XX XX. The format for UK can have 10, 9 or 7 digits . I think a "global" solution cannot be achieved easily.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_France



https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom#Format

Comment: @RaulLuna A tiny addition to your comment: UK phone numbers are *ten* or *eleven* digits, grouped in threes (5,3,3), in mainland Europe they are paired up (2,2,2,2,2).